# How do you change the Stepper color on React Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

In the screenshot above, I am trying to change the step color to either: green for correct, yellow for in-progress and red for incorrect.

How could I do this?

Comment: Material UI has added customizing `Steppers` to their documentation. Refer [here](https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/#customized-stepper)

Answer (score 27):

In case anyone is still looking for this question, for MUI 5 it is through the [sx property](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/) or [styled](https://mui.com/system/styled/).

Checkout what are the classes of [step](https://mui.com/api/step/), [stepIcon](https://mui.com/api/step-icon/) so you can customize the styles.

```
<Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
  <Stepper activeStep={currentStep} alternativeLabel>
    {Object.keys(steps).map((stepNumber) => (
      <Step
        key={stepNumber}
        sx={{
          '& .MuiStepLabel-root .Mui-completed': {
            color: 'secondary.dark', // circle color (COMPLETED)
          },
          '& .MuiStepLabel-label.Mui-completed.MuiStepLabel-alternativeLabel':
            {
              color: 'grey.500', // Just text label (COMPLETED)
            },
          '& .MuiStepLabel-root .Mui-active': {
            color: 'secondary.main', // circle color (ACTIVE)
          },
          '& .MuiStepLabel-label.Mui-active.MuiStepLabel-alternativeLabel':
            {
              color: 'common.white', // Just text label (ACTIVE)
            },
          '& .MuiStepLabel-root .Mui-active .MuiStepIcon-text': {
            fill: 'black', // circle's number (ACTIVE)
          },
        }}>
        <StepLabel>{steps[stepNumber].label}</StepLabel>
      </Step>
    ))}
  </Stepper>
</Box>
```

Comment: This is the proper way of doing it for MUI v5 but it's simpler to put the selector directly on the Stepper:

```javascriptreact
<Stepper sx={{'& .MuiStepIcon-root': {color: 'success'}}}>
{/* Your steps here */}
</Stepper>
```

Answer (score 13):

Update: Here is correct way for latest version 3. You just need to add the overrides correctly to your theme by referencing `MuiStepIcon`:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
   MuiStepIcon: {
    root: {
      '&$completed': {
        color: 'pink',
      },
      '&$active': {
        color: 'red',
      },
    },
    active: {},
    completed: {},
  },
  palette: {
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: You're a savior!

Answer (score 12):

Old question but in case anyone is looking.

You need to edit the theme and wrap it in `getMuiTheme`

```
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme'

const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
    stepper: {
        iconColor: 'green' // or logic to change color
    }
})

<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
    <Stepper>
        ...
    </Stepper>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

See https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/styles/getMuiTheme.js for full list of components and their default color schmemes.

You will see you can override colors on a per component basis and/or change the overall theme colors.

Answer (score 7):

This is a way I used to override it using classes overrides - all other properties remain the same.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  labelContainer: {
    "& $alternativeLabel": {
      marginTop: 0
    }
  },
  step: {
    "& $completed": {
      color: "lightgreen"
    },
    "& $active": {
      color: "pink"
    },
    "& $disabled": {
      color: "red"
    }
  },
  alternativeLabel: {},
  active: {}, //needed so that the &$active tag works
  completed: {},
  disabled: {},
  labelContainer: {
    "& $alternativeLabel": {
      marginTop: 0
    }
  },
});

class myStepper extends Component {

 render() {
   const { classes } = this.props;
   return(
        <Stepper
          activeStep={activeStep}
          alternativeLabel
          connector={connector}
          classes={{
            root: classes.root
          }}
        >
          {this.state.numberTasks.map(label => {
            return (
              <Step
                key={label}
                classes={{
                  root: classes.step,
                  completed: classes.completed,
                  active: classes.active
                }}
         >
        <StepLabel
          classes={{
            alternativeLabel: classes.alternativeLabel,
            labelContainer: classes.labelContainer
          }}
          StepIconProps={{
            classes: {
              root: classes.step,
              completed: classes.completed,
              active: classes.active,
              disabled: classes.disabled
            }
          }}
        >
          {this.state.labels[label - 1]} //label value here
        </StepLabel>
              </Step>
            );
          })}
        </Stepper>
);
}

export default withStyles(styles)(myStepper);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the classes property for the `StepIconProps` property:

part of JavaScript styles

```js
...
icon:{
  fill:"green",
},
text:{
  fill:"white",
},
...
```

```js
<Step key="someKey">
    <StepLabel StepIconProps={{
        classes: {
            active: classes.icon,
            text:   classes.text,
        }
    }}>
    Some Text
    </StepLabel>
</Step>
```

Then your style should overwrite the default theme color by using the `!important` CSS rule:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  icon: {
    color: "red !important"
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, first example is what I needed.

Comment: How do I just keep the step as blue sphere instead of numbered?
<Stepper  orientation="vertical">
        {steps.map((step) => (
          <Step>
            <StepLabel>
              {step.label}
            </StepLabel>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
I am unable to remove number and keep just blue dot/sphere for steps.

Answer (score 1):

Wish I could comment the answer by "@Piotr O", in regards to keeping the step numbers but do not have enough rep yet.

You need to set the `icon` prop to the `index` of the Step to keep the numbers.

`<Stepper activeStep={activeStep}>
  {steps.map((label, index) => {
    return (
      <Step>
        <StepLabel icon={index+1} />
      </Step>
    );
  })}
</Stepper>`

If you were to use different icons like you mentioned, you'd need some conditional logic to swap the icon via the `icon` prop or another possibility is to add the `className` prop to `<StepLabel />` when a condition is met and then style it with CSS.

I included an example with both concepts here: https://codesandbox.io/s/l5m570jq0l

Answer (score 1):

I did this via the sx property on the MobileStepper. I specifically wanted to change the colour of the dots indicating progress

```
<MobileStepper
    variant='dots'
    steps={maxSteps}
    ...
    sx={{
        '.MuiMobileStepper-dot': { backgroundColor: '#CCCCCC' },
        '.MuiMobileStepper-dotActive': { backgroundColor: '#666666' },
    }}
    ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change props icon of a `StepLabel` component as below:

```
<StepLabel
 icon={<WarningIcon color={red500} />}
 style={{color: red500}}
>
  Random label
</StepLabel>
```

Comment: That would work, but when i change the icon, i lost the numbers inside. how do i add those back?

Answer (score 0):

We need to pass the class to StepperLabel props . For example if we need to change alternativeLabel class then try the below:-

```
  <StepLabel
  StepIconComponent={stepperIcon} 
  classes={{
         alternativeLabel: classes.alternativeLabel,
          }}
   >
    <span className={cn(classes.label, labelClass)}>
       {'label'}
    </span>
  </StepLabel>
```