# How do you change the color of a stepper in material-ui in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Referring to this:
https://material-ui.com/demos/steppers/

It is blue by default.

I want it to be material-ui's orange200

I tried the following code (from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326565/how-do-you-change-the-stepper-color-on-react-material-ui)) but it did not work.

```
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme'

const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
    stepper: {
        iconColor: 'green' // or logic to change color
    }
})

<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
    <Stepper>
        ...
    </Stepper>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Chrome DevTools (or other browsers' dev tools) to find out a class that will give you an information about an element to override.

For example, assuming you found that the class name is 
`.MuiStepIcon-root-78`. The formulae is `Mui[component name]-[style rule name]-[UUID]`, where Mui is a default prefix and 78 is just an id. So, the element's name is `MuiStepIcon` and a subsequent attribute is `root`.

Say, you want to change the color. If you do the hierarchy `MuiStepIcon -> root -> color`, you will change the default color only. To change any other colors, watch out for `pseudo classes`. For example, using devtools, if the class is `.MuiStepIcon-root-78.MuiStepIcon-active-80`, then the pseudo class is `active`, and your code should be `MuiStepIcon -> root -> '&$active' -> color`. Look at the code below for references.

Look at the docs for more info https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes

You can also determine available elements to override by referring to `createMuiTheme -> overrides`, which will take you to `overrides.d.ts` file. There is an interface that lists all components names, like MuiStepIcon, though it won't give you other information as devtools do.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiStepIcon: {
            root: {
                color: '#000000', // or 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
                '&$active': {
                    color: '#000000',
                },
                '&$completed': {
                    color: '#000000',
                },
            },
        },
    }
});

const otherStyles = theme => ({
    root: {
        // Whatever needed
    },
});

class MyComponent extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}> 
            {
                // Your stepper here, should be within MuiThemeProvider
            }
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
};

export default withStyles(otherStyles, { withTheme: true })(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
overrides: {
    MuiStepIcon: {
        root: {
            color: '#000000', // or 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
            '&$active': {
                color: '#000000',
            },
            '&$completed': {
                color: '#000000',
            },
        },
    }
```

did work for me

Answer (score 0):

One way to change the color and styling of icon of stepper material UI is to pass icon prop in StepLabel as:

```
<StepLabel 
icon = <div style={{backgroundColor: 'orange', width:'11px', padding: '2px', textAlign: 'center', height: '11px', fontSize: '10px', borderRadius: '50%'}}>{index}</div>
>{label}</StepLabel>
```

Comment: this isn't working it has a compiile error for putting <div> inside of StepLabel. I'm not trying to change the label, I'm trying to change the stepper.

Comment: In order to change StepLabel you can find working code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jn72jooyyw

Comment: Which version of material-UI are you using? If you are on v0 you can use getMuiTheme but in v1 it is deprecated, for v1 you can user createMuiTheme, for overriding styling for stepper MuiStepper is used as the component.

Comment: I used the labelProps and that worked! However, it doesn't include the functionality of being grey when not completed as well rendering a check mark when it is complete instead of always showing the number using index. This method pretty much hijacks the Step rendering function and instead renders the div of icon. Do you know how to add the functionality described?